# VSCode: SCSS not compiling to CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I’m working in VSCode using HTML, SCSS, and Javascript. I was working on it and suddenly came across a bug which led to 2 hours of time wasted to find out the SCSS has stopped compiling to the main style.css sheet. All the extensions are working fine. I have the sass --watch extension and it is ‘watching’.

When I make changes directly from the main style.css sheet I can see the updates on the browser. So the issue is just the SCSS to CSS. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share more details? Is the process just frozen? Does it throw any error message? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: yeah, the process just froze. It was working fine and suddenly stopped

Comment: I went ahead to delete the generated files but ended up creating more problems.., i am exhausted